# Selenium RC: I am unable run test suite in firefox or any other browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

I am newbie with Selenium. I recently encountered with one failure that I could not overcome.
I am trying to run next suite in firefox or chrome:

```
C:\auto_tools>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -htmlSuite "*googlechrome C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://google.com" "D:\Selenium_2.0\Selenium_tests\Selenium_IDE&Selenium Builder\Selenium_start\test_suit.html" "D:\Selenium_2.0\Selenium_tests\Selenium_IDE&Selenium Builder\Selenium_start\results.html"
```

As answer I am see chrome browser with:

http://google.com/selenium-server/core/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&resultsUrl=../postResults&test=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fselenium-server%2Ftests%2Ftest_suit.html

and

> 23:02:46.698 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
>
> 23:02:46.825 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02 23:02:46.826
>   INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64 23:02:46.838 INFO - v2.46.0, with Core
>   v2.46.0. Built from revision 87c69e2  23:02:46.897 INFO - Driver class
>   not found:com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver  23:02:46.897 INFO -
>   Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered 
>   23:02:47.096 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...

with *firefox path/to/firefox.exe - same issue...

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I found out that the reason was that my antivirus blocked connection to localhost including port 4444 - thats why I could not run test suit.

Comment: Thats the antivirus was blocking my all local ports